# SQL query with distinct values while using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

avoid Previous posted question.

I am using inner join to join the table, `lotid` and `date` is from `test` table and `worker` is from `test1` table. I am using `group by` but it is not working because worker and date column is different

```
lotid worker date
1234  abc    02/02/2106
1234  xyz    03/03/2016
```

but in the output I should get only 1 lotid

```
lotid worker date
1234   abc   02/02/2016
```

how to achieve that?

Comment: I am using mssql database

Comment: I suggesst you use RANK() or DENSE_RANK() to get only 1 lotid please see this url below  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx

Comment: in the url i see the productid is getting duplicate but haveing different rank, but it will not help my cause

Comment: What is the query you tried?

Comment: select lotid,date,worker from test
inner join test1
on test.lotid=test1.totid
group by lotid,date,worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your helps folks but I figured out the solution,

```
select lotid,
max(worker) as worker
max(trsdate) as max_date
from test
inner join test1
on test.lotid=test1.lotid
group by lotid
```

Answer (score 0):

I make simple table and simple query use DENSE_RANK() below

```
CREATE TABLE #test (lotid NVARCHAR(10), workDate DATETIME)
CREATE TABLE #test1 (lotid NVARCHAR(10),worker NVARCHAR(10) )

INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('1234','2016-02-02'),('1234','2016-03-03')

INSERT INTO #test1 VALUES ('1234','abc'),('1234','xyz')


SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.*
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.lotid ORDER BY t.workDate ASC) AS [r]
    FROM #test t 
    INNER JOIN #test1 t1 ON t.lotid = t1.lotid
) q
WHERE q.r = 1

DROP TABLE #test
DROP TABLE #test1
```

and result is :

> lotid | workDate | r
>
> 1234  | 2016-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 1

Comment: I am getting close but if i am having rank like 2,2,3,4,5,5. how to count the 2 and 5 only once

Comment: what current result did you get ?

Comment: Above query was just a scenario, after looking your code i tried using dense_rank() and where there is duplicate lotid i m getting the rank as 2,2 and so on. so how to count it only once

Comment: I don't understand if you follow my query result set must not contain rank = 2 and lotid must not duplicate can you post a part of result you get and your query

Comment: Rank size pcktno RoughWeight QuantityBalance LotID LotName Worker TrsDate
1 2CT Q161124 2.042 1 71717011 R16106921-0034 Warut Suwannarat 2016-02-03 12:42:00
2 2CT Q161124 1.842 1 71717038 R16106921-0042 Piyanat Prakit 2016-02-02 05:45:00
2 2CT Q161124 1.842 1 71717038 R16106921-0042 Sirirat Phasaengtharn 2016-02-02 09:52:00
3 2CT Q161124 2.060 1 71717045 R16106921-0048 Warut Suwannarat 2016-02-03 09:49:00

Comment: where q.r=1 is only returning rank 1 what if there is 2 time 2 and so on

Comment: can you post your query ?

Comment: give me your email id, i will email it to you

Comment: chanon.kitk@hotmail.com